# Matrix multiplication in a cpp file for Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix

How would I do a matrix multiplication in `cpp` format that would after be compiled into a `mex` file?

My normal matrix multiplication in a Matlab script is as follow:

```
cMatrix = (1 / r) * pfMatrix * wcMatrix; %here pfMatrix is 2x3 and wcMatrix is 3x8
% Hence cMatrix is 2x8
% r is a scalar
```

The pfMatrix, wcMatrix and r are declared correctly in the `cpp` file and they have the same values as in the script. However cMatrix doesn't give me the same results. Here the implementation of the Matrix multiplication in the `cpp` :

```
    int i, n, j;
    for (i = 0; i<1; i++)
    {
        for (n = 0; n<7; n++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j<2; j++)
            {
                d->cMatrix[i][n] += (d->pfMatrix[i][j]) * (d->wcMatrix[j][n]);
            }
            d->cMatrix[i][n] = (1 / d->r) * d->cMatrix[i][n];
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

I modified the loop following [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528301/2419003) answer. The results in `cMatrix` are still not identical to the one calculated from the Matlab script.

For example :

```
pfMatrix = [7937.91049469652,0,512;0,7933.81033431703,384];
wcMatrix = [-0.880633810389421,-1.04063381038942,-1.04063381038942,-0.880633810389421,-0.815633810389421,-1.10563381038942,-1.10563381038942,-0.815633810389421;-0.125,-0.125,0.125,0.125,-0.29,-0.29,0.29,0.29;100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100];
r = 100;
```

In this case, `cMatrix(1,1)` is :

```
(pfMatrix(1,1)*wcMatrix(1,1) + pfMatrix(1,2)*wcMatrix(2,1) + pfMatrix(1,3)*wcMatrix(3,1)) / r = 442.09
```

However, with the `mex` file the equivalent result is `959`.

**Edit #2:**

I found the error in an element of `pfMatrix` that was not declared correctly (missing a division by 2). So the answer of [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528301/2419003) is working correctly. However, there is still a slight difference between the two results (Matlab script gives 442 and the mex gives 447, could it be a results of different data type?).

**Edit #3:**

Found the error and it was not related with the matrix multiplication loop.

Comment: I assume that all of this is in a [proper `mex` file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-mex-files-to-call-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html)?

Comment: @horchler Indeed, the mex file is created without any error. It can be called without any error. The only problem is that the output `cMatrix` is not correct.

Comment: Did you set all elements of `cMatrix` to zero before adding to them?

Comment: I assume that you mean that `wcMatrix` is 3-by-8?

Comment: @BenVoigt cMatrix is initialized like this in the class : `double cMatrix[2][8];`

Comment: @horchler Yes I meant 3-by-8. I made the correction.

Comment: @m_power: That's a definition without initialization.  I guess it contains arbitrary values initially.  In fact, you'll have undefined behavior as a result.

Comment: Concerning your last edit, I see that MATLAB produces 447 for a different element of the result.  Could there be a row-column-major ordering issue here?  Can you at least check if all the results are matching in value but out of order?

Comment: @BenVoigt I found the error, it was a bad indexing in the initialization of wcMatrix. So not related to the loop itself.

Comment: @m_power: If my answer is working for you after fixing bugs elsewhere in your code, you might consider removing the comment below it that says it's merely "closer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your result matrix as scratch space is not a great idea.  The compiler has to worry about aliasing, which means it can't optimize.

Try an explicit working variable, which also provides a convenient place to zero it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    for (int n = 0; n < 8; ++n) {
        double accum = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            accum += (d->pfMatrix[i][j]) * (d->wcMatrix[j][n]);
        }
        d->cMatrix[i][n] = accum / d->r;
    }
}
```

Your ranges were also wrong, which I've fixed.

(Also note that good performance on large matrices requires banding to get good cache behavior, however that shouldn't be an issue on a product of this size.)

Answer (score 0):

A multiplication between matrices must be in this way: A[m][n] * B[n][p] = R[m][p].

The conditions that you wrote in the for loops are not correct and doesn't respect the matrix dimensions.

Look also at the Eigen libraries, which are open-source and provide a simple way to do the matrix multiplications.

Comment: His multiplication looks fine, although he uses `i`, `j`, `n` instead of `m`, `n`, `p`.

Comment: Oh I was looking at the code rather than the comments.  I figured the dimensions had to be compatible if the MATLAB version was working.